# Type-Checking in Functions between Python 2.7 and Python 3.3

Tags: python, function, types, python-3.x, python-2.7

In my functions, I check for the types of the input so that it is valid (example - for a function that checks the primality of 'n', I don't want 'n' to be inputted as a string).
The problem occurs with checking for `long`s and `int`s.
In Python 3.3, they removed the `long`-type number, so the problem occurs with this:

```
def isPrime(n):
    """Checks if 'n' is prime"""
    if not isinstance(n, int): raise TypeError('n must be int')
    # rest of code
```

This works universally for both v2.7 and v3.3.
However, if I import this function in a Python 2.7 program, and enter a `long`-type number for 'n', like this: `isPrime(123456789000)`, it would obviously raise a `TypeError` because 'n' is of the type `long`, not `int`.

So, how can I check if it is valid input for both v2.7 and v3.3 for `long`s and `int`s?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean `isPrime(123456789000L)`?

Comment: @DavidRobinson `isPrime(123456789000L)` and `isPrime(123456789000)` are essentially the same thing: `isinstance(123456789000L, int)` and `isinstance(123456789000, int)` both return `False`.

Comment: On what version of Python? `isinstance(123456789000, int)` returns `True` for me on both Python 2.6 and Python 2.7.

Comment: (I'm guessing the issue is between 64-bit and 32-bit Python)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A way I can think of is:

```
from numbers import Integral

>>> blah = [1, 1.2, 1L]
>>> [i for i in blah if isinstance(i, Integral)]
[1, 1L]
```

**edit** (after an insightful comment from @martineau)

Python 2.7:

```
>>> map(type, [1, 1.2, 2**128])
[<type 'int'>, <type 'float'>, <type 'long'>]
```

Python 3.3:

```
>>> list(map(type, [1, 1.2, 2**128]))
[<class 'int'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'int'>]
```

The example still stands that using `isinstance(n, numbers.Integral)` but stands more coherent.

Comment: This is the *only* way you should do this.

Comment: In Python 3 I get an invalid syntax error pointing to the `L` in `blah = [1, 1.2, 1L]`.

Comment: @martineau That makes sense... as there is no `long` type in Py3. It was to demonstrate using Py2.7 (or actually from 2.6) that it's possible to use `Integral` for `int` and `long` or just `int`...

Comment: Right...still surprises me considering the OP wanted to "check if it is valid input for both v2.7 and v3.3", so maybe using `blah = [1, 1.2, 123456789000]` as an example valid in both versions would have been more coherent.

Comment: @martineau yup - made an update to the post to reflect your comment - feel free to edit if you feel you can make it clearer

Answer (score 0):

```
def isPrime(n):
    """Checks if 'n' is prime"""
    try:
        n = int(n)
    except:
        raise TypeError('n must be int')
    # rest of code
```

Comment: That converts strings and similiar into numbers, rather then just doing type checking -> not what the op wanted, or a good idea.

Answer (score -2):

From: http://docs.python.org/3.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#integers

The sys.maxint constant was removed, since there is no longer a limit to the value of integers. However, sys.maxsize can be used as an integer larger than any practical list or string index. It conforms to the implementation’s “natural” integer size and is typically the same as sys.maxint in previous releases on the same platform (assuming the same build options).

```
if not isinstance(n, int) or n > sys.maxsize: raise TypeError('n must be int')
```

may work for differentiating int and long.

Comment: That's the exact opposite of what the OP is requesting.

Comment: Won't converting the input to int using int(n) work in that case? Instead of TypeError, ValueError can by returned.